# Clicking outside SVG container

Tags: css, svg, safari

I'm using d3 to generate some graphs and it results that a points falls partially outside the svg element.

The problem comes when using Safari, it doesn't detect neither the hover nor the click event.
Here is a fiddle that shows whats happening: 
    `http://jsfiddle.net/3a5AN/72/`

In chrome it works okay, but in safari it doesn't even trigger the `cursor:pointer;`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and as suggested I had to set the width and height of the SVG to the browser width

This is how mine works

```
let width = window.innerWidth;
let height = window.innerHeight;

const svg = $window.d3.select('#svgContainer')
    .append('svg')
    .style('width', width + 'px')
    .style('height', height + 'px');
```

And then of course add a listener to the browser resize to update the width and height on resize.